# EOF exception for readObject

Tags: java, serialization, eof, objectoutputstream

i am wondering if there is anyway to check if a `ObjectInputStream` or `ObjectOutputStream` is empty or not. i mean, in my program. at first time when it runs, the `ObjectInputStream` will use its `readObject()` method then because still the file empty it gives me an `EOF` exception( end of file) so i would like to check if it is empty or not then get rid off the exception:

And am i doing it right? for Serializing, i made the class with same name and attribute as below in both client and server.

```
public class KeyAdr implements Serializable{

 String adr;
 String key;


}
....

    static FileInputStream fIn=null;
    static ObjectInputStream oIn=null;
    private static KeyAdr test=new KeyAdr();

....

           fIn= new FileInputStream("d:\\someFile.ser");
           oIn = new ObjectInputStream(fIn);
           test= (KeyAdr) oIn.readObject();
```

## EDIT:

```
 static  File serAdrKey=new File("d:\\someFile.ser");
     static    ObjectOutputStream oOut;
     static    FileOutputStream fOut;
     static  final   Pattern WebUrlPattern = Pattern.compile (WebUrlRegex);
     private static String WebUrlStr;
     static KeyAdr letsDoIt= new KeyAdr();

....

 public static void openStreams() throws IOException
        {
         fOut= new FileOutputStream(serAdrKey);
     oOut = new ObjectOutputStream(fOut);

        }


        @Override
public void    beforeWindowOpen(NavigationEvent event) 
        {

                     temp=event.getURL().toString();


  Matcher WebUrlMatcher = WebUrlPattern.matcher (temp);
    if (WebUrlMatcher.matches ())
    {
        int n = WebUrlMatcher.groupCount ();
      for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i) {
    WebUrlStr = WebUrlMatcher.group (i);

}

                    letsDoIt.adr=WebUrlStr;    

                    try {
                    oOut.writeObject(letsDoIt);

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Cobratest2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }


                   try {
                oOut.flush();


                   } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Cobratest2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
```

## Edit 2

```
fIn= new FileInputStream("d:\\someFile.ser");
PushbackInputStream input = new PushbackInputStream(fIn);
int c = input.read();
if(c != -1)
{
  input.unread(c);
  oIn = new ObjectInputStream(input);
  test = (KeyAdr) oIn.readObject();
  // ......
}
```

## Edit 3:

the Edit2 codes gave me following exception with the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2552)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1297)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
        at test.Test.processClient(Test.java:117)
            at test.Test.run(Test.java:92)
            at test.Test.main(Test.java:159)
```

Comment: Where did you initialize the ObjectOuputStream?

Comment: @Phani i added it to the Question. i forgot to write it here

Comment: See my edit of your 2nd edit.

Comment: @EJP how about my edit3?

Comment: Sorry, I've been leading you up the garden path. You need to construct the `PushbackInputStream` first, test its first read(), push the result back, etc, *then* construct the `ObjectInputStream`. Constructing an `ObjectInputStream` does a read, so you don't want to do that first.

Comment: @EJP got same error this time as soon as client starts hmm :(

Comment: Impossible. See my revised edit 2.

Comment: @lonesome If you read the PushbackInputStream; don't get a -1; push that back into the PushbackInputStream; and then construct an ObjectInputStream around the PushbackInputStream, it will read what you pushed back, not EOF. It works for me. It is still possible that the file only has one byte in it, or in general an incomplete object write, in which case your real problem is at the producing end, not here. NB most of those static members in your code should be local variables, and you should ensure that all streams are closed after use.

Comment: @EJP seems fixed when i made some declration as local, but there is another problem, at readobject, although i created class as i mentioned in the question,it gives me the exception that didnt find the class... simply, i created two classed in client and server side with same name and same field, is there possibly something that im missing?

Comment: @lonesome You should have created *one* class and deployed the same .class file to both client and server. No doubt what you have done is copied the source code from one package to another. That doesn't work.

Comment: @EJP well i mentioned it in my question and nobody said a word :)

Comment: @lonesome You said nothing about changing packages, if that's what you did, and if that's what you did that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: @EJP ooh i see, but anyway, thanks for answering my questions patiently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use the `read` method first to check if there is at least 1 byte.

`read()` is guaranteed to return -1 when the end of the stream has been reached, if the very first `read()` returns -1 the file must be empty

Addendum:
Using the FileInputStream you should be able to mark/reset to avoid losing the read byte.

You may however want to use java.util.File to check emptiness of the file beforehand.

Comment: This will **most definitely** not work. It will throw away data that serialization needs.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to check if it is empty or not then get rid off the exception:

Why? That's what the EOFException is *for.*

Comment: @lonesome You can't fix your code to eliminate the exception. It will always happen when you reach end of file, and you can't be sure when that's going to occur.